# Flat permutations of n-tuple (breadth first)

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I'd like to enumerate an n-tuple. For instance for n=2:

```
00 01 10 11
02 20 12 21 22
03 30 13 31 23 32 33
04 40 14 41 ...
```

n=3 would start like this:

```
000 001 010 100 011 101 110 111
002 020 200 012 102 021 120 201 210 112 121 211 122 212 221 222
003 ...
```

The order of tuples with the same elements is not important (e.g. 001 and 010), but tuples with more (011 vs 001) or more importantly larger (002 vs 001) elements should always come later.

After some search, there appeared to be many related algorithms, but none specifically for this case. Is there such an algorithm?

Edit: An image of the n=2 case. Green lines denote elements that are reached by shuffling the order of elements in a tuple.

[image]

Edit: Clarification about the order:

1. Tuples are primarily sorted by their maximum element (152 > 444)
2. Then sorted by their second largest element (053 > 252) and so on (12341 > 12340)
3. Order among tuples with the same elements is arbitrary (123 = 321)

Comment: Did you try n-ry representation? For example, for alphabet={0,1} will be the binary representation of the number (There are simple algorithm for calculating this). Why is it not working for you?

Comment: @amit: I'm not sure but wouldn't that result in a sequence like 000 001 002 010 011 012 020 ... ? I want to resort to larger elements (the '2' in this example) as late as possible.

Comment: I see. And does the order between 010 to 002 matter? which should be first? If I follow you correctly, 010 should be first.

Comment: Also: What is the size of the permutation? Is an algorithm that goes through all of them and give them numbers realistic (as pre-processing) or the size is large, and considering the exponential behavior of the combinations - it should be done on the fly?

Comment: @amit: Yes, exactly. All tuples containing a 'n+1' are after any tuples that only have elements up to 'n', for instance 005 is after 444.

Comment: @amit: In my specific case, the dimension will be at most 4. The elements are at most 13, so there are exactly 13^4 combinations - unless there is an early exit, which will always be the case. Thus if possible, the algorithm should not compute and store all combinations then sort them because that would require a lot of space and time, far more than necessary.

Comment: 13^4 = 28561, it is really not much space (unless this is embedded system), and storing it once in pre-processing really is pretty easy. I'd go for it, but if I think of some on-the-fly method to calculate the enumeration, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: it took `.08s` with some very simple code to generate the cartesian product and sort them in the order you like, for the case of n=4 and 13 elements. for n=5 it took 1.5seconds. note that this you'd only have to do once and then you can iterate through the list any other time. if that's sufficient lemme know and i'll post the code; working on an on-the-fly one too though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `seq(n, k)` yield the sequence you want with `k` digits per entry, with digits from `0` to `n`.

Let step `i` be the phase that generates all tuples where the maximum digit is `i`.

At each step, we simply generate the `i+1`-ary representation of all the numbers up to `(i+1) ** (k - 1) - 1` (i.e. up to `k-1` digits). For each `i+1`-ary representation, we then produce the elements of the sequence by inserting the digit `i` at each location in the `i+1`-ary representation.

In order to avoid duplicates, we break early in the case we encounter an `i` already in the `i+1`-ary representation.

Here is an (ugly!) sample implementation in python:

```
def to_nary_string(num, n):
    if num == 0:
        return "0"

    result = ""
    while num != 0:
        result = str(num % n) + result
        num /= n

    return result

def seq(n, k):
    print "0" * k

    for i in range(2, n+2):
        for x in range(i**(k-1)):
            stem = to_nary_string(x, i).zfill(k-1)
            c = str(i-1)
            for j in range(k):
                print stem[:j] + c + stem[j:],               
                if j != k-1 and stem[j] == c:
                    break
        print
```

**EDIT:** The problem with this is that the `k-1` digit strings have to be in the same order as the tuples, not sequential `n`-ary order. Changing the function slightly gives the desired result:

```
# Original list and string version
def seq(n, k):
    if (k == 0):
        return [""]

    result = []

    for i in range(n+1):
        c = str(hex(i))[2:] # 10 -> a, 11-> b, etc.

        for subseq in seq(i, k-1):
            for j in range(k):
                result.append(subseq[:j] + c + subseq[j:])
                if j != k-1 and subseq[j] == c:
                    break

    return result
```

Also, thanks to Claudiu, here is a generator and tuple version

```
# Generator and tuple version
#
# Thanks Claudiu!

def seq(n, k):
    if (k == 0):
        yield ()
        return

    for i in range(n+1):
        for subseq in seq(i, k-1):
            for j in range(k):
                yield subseq[:j] + (i,) + subseq[j:]
                if j != k-1 and subseq[j] == i:
                    break
```

Result (Line breaks added for clarity):

```
>>> for x in seq(4, 2):
    print x,

00
10 01 11
20 02 21 12 22
30 03 31 13 32 23 33
40 04 41 14 42 24 43 34 44

>>> for x in seq(3, 3):
    print x,

000
100 010 001
110 101 011
111
200 020 002
210 120 102 201 021 012
211 121 112
220 202 022
221 212 122
222
300 030 003
310 130 103 301 031 013
311 131 113
320 230 203 302 032 023
321 231 213 312 132 123
322 232 223
330 303 033
331 313 133
332 323 233
333
```

And a quick sanity check:

```
>>> len(seq(12, 4)) == 13 ** 4
True
```

Comment: I just noticed there is a slight problem with the ordering, I misread the question. Will look into it. :)

Comment: Nice! I'm learning python while reading your answer so it takes a moment to fully understand it. In the output sequence, 202 is too early, it should follow after all cases of a single '2' in the tuple. I didn't write it clearly, sorry.

Comment: @mafutrct Yep, the problem was the `k-1` length strings have to be in the same order as the tuples, not `n`-ary order (e.g. `.. 01, 10, 11, 02 ..` not `.. 01, 02, 10, 11, ..`. I've updated the answer, note it is now recursive and I'm pretty sure it ends up calculating some intermediate results multiple times, but it's a starting point.

Comment: @mafutrct Made one small tweak, `c` is now converted to hex since you need digits up to 13. Previously it broke for `n >= 10` since `str(10)` is not a single character. Also confirmed `seq(12, 4)` has `13 ** 4` elements, as expected. Also `len(seq(15, 6)) == 16777216` takes only a couple seconds on my box so I'm not so fussed about memoisation. `k > 6` would probably be pushing it. :)

Comment: here is a [generator version](http://pastebin.com/K9ekKrDx) of that code, also using tuples instead of strings, in case that is what is preferred - personally makes more sense to me to have a generator as you want to iterate through it and break at some point

Comment: @Claudiu Thanks! I was trying to work out how to do that but I've never written an iterator in python before. That's why I ended up just posting the list version.

Comment: it confused me a bit too at first. basic principle: yield every element instead of appending it to the list. so `return [""]` --> `yield ""; return`, `result = ["0"*k]` --> `yield "0"*k`, `result.append(foo)` --> `yield foo`

Comment: @Claudiu: Thanks! Yes, I like tuples better. Maybe edit-append it to this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: your edit made this ordering invalid. Left here for posterity.

Here is the algorithm I implemented in english. Basically, in order to get the ordering you want, think of the problem as "generating all n-tuples with at least one of a given largest element". Assuming we have that, all we have to do is:

```
- yield `n` zeroes
- for each element greater than zero:
  - yield all the n-tuples with at least one of that element
```

In order to generate all n-tuples with at least one of a given largest element, I generated all possible positions the element might be in - e.g. for a 3-tuple those would be

```
no  no  yes
no  yes no
no  yes yes
yes no  no
yes no  yes
yes yes no 
yes yes yes
```

It's just the cartesian product of `n` (yes, no) choices. For each possible position, we fill in all possible `no`s. What can go in the `no`s? Any element that is smaller than the largest element. So to do that, you take the cartesian product of all elements smaller than the largest (including zero), `x` times, where `x` is the number of `no`s, and fill in those blanks too. So if you have largest_el is `3` and the position is `no no yes` then you do:

```
0 0 3
0 1 3
0 2 3
1 0 3
1 1 3
1 2 3
2 0 3
2 1 3
2 2 3
```

Here is a python implementation of that algorithm:

```
import itertools
alphabet = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
def enumerate_n_tuples(n):
    #the zero case:
    yield [alphabet[0],]*n
    for i in xrange(1, len(alphabet)):
        #alphabet[i] is the largest element
        #it must be present in the result
        largest_el = alphabet[i]
        #fill in the largest element in all possible combinations
        for largest_el_map in itertools.product(*([(False,True)]*n)):
            #other spots are filled freely up to (not including) largest
            num_others = sum(1 for largest in largest_el_map
                             if not largest)
            if num_others == n: continue #need at least one largest el
            for others in itertools.product(*([alphabet[:i]]*num_others)):
                #init the result to zeroes
                res = [alphabet[0]]*n
                #fill in the largest elements, putting the other
                #elements in between
                others_i = 0
                for j,largest in enumerate(largest_el_map):
                    if largest:
                        res[j] = largest_el
                    else:
                        res[j] = others[others_i]
                        others_i += 1
                yield res
```

Example:

```
>>> for threetup in enumerate_n_tuples(3):
        print threetup
        if threetup[-1]==3: break


[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
```

Comment: Sorry for not wording it clearly initially. Your code is a little intimidating yet (because I'm not fluent in python) but the general format is very good, maybe it can be 'fixed' to conform to the intended output.

Comment: it's alright. i posted the other solution to show how much easier it is to modify things if you do it that way. for this i have to come up with a new algorithm, but for the other i just had to change 2 lines of code. also put the english explanation up to help with non-python fluency

Answer (score 1):

Ok, given that your `n` is at most 4 and you only have 13 elements, this is really the best way to do it:

```
import itertools

alphabet = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

def tup_sort_key(t):
    largest_el = max(t)
    z = list(t)
    z.sort(reverse=True)
    return tuple(z)

def gen_all_n_tuples(n):
    all_els = list(itertools.product(*([alphabet]*n)))
    all_els.sort(key=tup_sort_key)
    return all_els
```

Brief explanation: generate all possible tuples, and simply apply the sort ordering you want (largest element, second largest, third largest, etc.). This takes less than 0.2 seconds for n=4.

Result:

```
>>> print "\n".join(map(str, gen_all_n_tuples(3)))
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(2, 0, 2)
(2, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 2)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 3, 0)
(3, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 3, 1)
(1, 0, 3)
(1, 3, 0)
(3, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 3)
(0, 3, 2)
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This algorithm generates the next element that satisfies your constraints.

generateNext(int a[1:m]) {
  Let n be the largest number in a.
  IF a[i] == n  for all i: {     // e.g. If a = 111
     set a[1] = n+1 and a[j] = 0 for all j in 2 to m.
     return
  }
  ELSE {
     Let p be the last position where n appears.
     IF a[i] == n for all i to the left of p {         // trivially true when p is 1.
         set a[i] = 0 for all i to the left of p.
        IF a[i] == n-1 for all i to the right of p {  // trivially true when p is m.
           set a[i] = 0 for all i to the right of p.
           set a[p-1] = n
        } 
        ELSE {
           generateNext(a[p+1:m])
           seta[i] = 0 for all i to the left of p
        }        
     }
     ELSE 
       generateNext(a[1:p-1])
  }
}
```

When called with 002 the sequence of numbers the algorithm returns should be:
002 012 102 112 022 122 202 212 222 020 120 220 021 121 221 200 201 210 211

Comment: Yes, just realized that this doesn't satisfy the requirement that tuples with more elements should come later. I didn't notice this requirement.

Comment: it's not about more elements, it's that its sorted by the 1st largest, then 2nd largest, then 3rd largest, etc

Answer (score 0):

For reference, a port of veredesmarald's answer with Claudiu's implementation to C#. Python's arrays sure are more concise.

```
public IEnumerable<List<int>> Enumerate (int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0) {
        yield return new List<int> ();
        yield break;
    }

    yield return Enumerable.Repeat (0, k).ToList ();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        foreach (var x in Enumerate (i, k - 1)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                var res = x.Take (j).Concat (new int[] { i }).Concat (x.Skip (j));
                yield return res.ToList ();
                if (j != k - 1 && x[j] == i) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public IEnumerable<List<int>> Enumerate (int k)
{
    return Enumerate (int.MaxValue, k);
}

// Test:
foreach (var tuple in Enumerate (3).Take (100)) {
    Console.Write (string.Concat (tuple.Select (x => x.ToString ())) + " ");
    if (tuple.All (x => x == tuple[0])) {
        Console.WriteLine ();
    }
}
```